# Dual nationality, Australian + British. Can I return to Australia if I only have UK passport and Australian citizenship form?

Tags: uk, dual-nationality, australian-citizens

I have dual Australian/British nationality and have been living in the UK for the past 8 years. I currently only have a British passport but still have my Australian citizenship document. My sister booked my flight back to Australia without checking if I can return on the UK passport and show passport control and the airline my Australian citizenship form?

I'm extremely worried as I leave in 4 days but only found out about the potential problem just now.

Comment: Have you phoned the airline?

Comment: not as yet, i'm more concerned about the actual arrival in oz part. the airline would probably be the easy part but i will call them in the morning.

Comment: Without an Australian passport, the airline is likely to require that you have an Australian visa associated with your British passport.

Comment: Australia will let you in (they have to!), although it will take some time.  As phoog says, your problem will be the airline.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, Australian citizens are required to present an Australian passport when entering Australia. According to [Travel documents for entry to Australia](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Goin/Arrival/Travel-Documents-for-Entry-to-Australia):

> Australian citizens have an automatic right of entry to Australia, and do not require a visa. Australian citizens need only to present the following documents to officers in immigration clearance:
>
> - a valid Australian passport or other acceptable travel document
> - a completed and signed Incoming Passenger Card.
>
> Australians who hold dual or multiple nationalities should hold an Australian passport and use it to enter or leave Australia, even when using a foreign passport overseas. The only exception is where they have been issued with an Australian Declaratory Visa.

The same page has this to say about the Australian Declaratory Visa:

> The Australian Declaratory Visa (ADV) is an administrative document that resembles a visa. It is issued in limited circumstances to Australian citizens who hold dual nationality, only if the applicant either:
>
> - is a dual national under the age of 18
> - has an emergency or other situation preventing travel on an Australian passport.
>
> The Australian Declaratory Visa is valid for five years from the date of issue, unless the holder ceases to be an Australian citizen, in which case the holder will need a normal visa to travel to Australia.
>
> Charges apply for this service.

The question for you is whether they would consider your situation an "emergency or other situation" that qualifies you to get an ADV. I would call the [Australian High Commission](http://uk.embassy.gov.au/) immediately and ask them what your best course of action is.